# queryEqualTo is being skipped over

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to set up a viewCount for my app, when I set the breakpoints up and go through the code it always skips past the queryOrdered and i'm not exactly sure why

```
func increaseViewCount(username: String, time: NSNumber){
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{
        return
    }
    let refOfUserName = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(uid)
    refOfUserName.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
        let dictionaryOfUser = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
       // let currentUsersName = dictionaryOfUser?["username"] as? String
    let currentUsersName = "hello"

        if username == currentUsersName {
            print("this is the same user")

        }else{

            let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("HistoryOfPosts").child("post")
            postRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "post").queryEqual(toValue: time).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: {(snapshotPost) in

                print(snapshotPost.exists())
                print(snapshotPost)

                let valString = snapshotPost.value
                let number = valString as! NSNumber
                var value = number.intValue
                value = value + 1
                let values = ["viewCount": value] as [String:Any]
                postRef.updateChildValues(values)

            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded from the Firebase Database asynchronously. Instead of waiting for that loading to complete, the program continues with the statement *after* you attach the observer.

In this case that means that the code pretty much exits `increaseViewCount()` straight after it attaches the observer. Then once the data comes back from the Firebase servers, the code in your callback block is executed.

To get *into* the callback block, place a breakpoint on the first statement in that block.